# when Qt shared library is loaded?

Tags: shared-libraries

I know shared files should be loaded using dlopen(),and then get function address by dlsym(),but I didn't use those calls on any Qt's shared library,instead I just include corresponding .h file.
So,when those .so files are loaded?

Comment: When the executable is being loaded

Comment: I mean when  dlopen and dlsym is called

Comment: They are not unless you write them into your code.